# \underbrace and align environment

Tags: math-mode, align, underbrace

I want to typeset a proof and want to emphasize what I do in each step e.g. by underbracing an equal-sign when I substitute a variable. In addition I also want to align equal-signs in every line. Unfortunately I don't know how to align an underbraced equal-sign and a non underbraced equal-sign at the same time.

[image: Result of the MWE]

Question: How can I align the underbraced and the non underbraced equal-sign vertically?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathe
\usepackage{mathtools} % Mathe
\usepackage{amsfonts} % Mathesymbole

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    D(D^TD)^{-1} &\underbrace{=}_{\mathclap{D=B(B^TB)^{-1}}} B(B^TB)^{-1}((B(B^TB)^{-1})^TB(B^TB)^{-1})^{-1} \\
      &= B(B^TB)^{-1}(((B^TB)^{-1})^TB^TB(B^TB)^{-1})^{-1}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use a `\dagger` or something similar for pseudo-inverses. It will be impossible to read if you do that.

Comment: It is not a pseuso inverse `B^T*B` is a regular (square) matrix, so the inverse is well-defined.

I want to show that if `L(D)=L(B(B^T*B)^{-1})` is a lattice (discrete additive subgroup of R^m) then L(B) is the dual lattice of L(D). For more information see [exercise 4](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi12/cse206A-a/LecDual.pdf) in this lecture note.

Comment: I wouldn't even use the underbrace. Instead mention it in the text before or after the formula. Adding an underbrace to explain an equality does not look nice typographically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need first of all to make the `\underbrace` a math relation, for spacing; but you also have to extend the space reserved to it, because an underbrace has a minimum width:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathe
\usepackage{mathtools} % Mathe
\usepackage{amsfonts} % Mathesymbole
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\ueq}[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \sbox0{$\underbrace{=}_{}$}%
    \mathrel{\mathmakebox[\wd0]{=}}
  \else
    \mathrel{\underbrace{=}_{\mathclap{#1}}}
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    D(D^TD)^{-1} &\ueq[D=B(B^TB)^{-1}] B(B^TB)^{-1}((B(B^TB)^{-1})^TB(B^TB)^{-1})^{-1} \\
      &\ueq B(B^TB)^{-1}(((B^TB)^{-1})^TB^TB(B^TB)^{-1})^{-1}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

So, if `\ueq` has no optional argument it produces an equal sign as wide as an underbraced one, otherwise it adds the underbrace.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I encourage others who have similar (but not identical) situations to play around with ``\mathrel``, ``\mathclap`` and the package ``aligned-overset``. There is hope.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative to what you want, which still conveys the same information without decorating equals signs with equations.  The traditional way to annotate steps in a derivation is with labels.  So you could instead do

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathe
\usepackage{mathtools} % Mathe
\usepackage{amsfonts} % Mathesymbole

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    D(D^TD)^{-1} 
      &= B(B^TB)^{-1}((B(B^TB)^{-1})^TB(B^TB)^{-1})^{-1}  \label{subst}\\
      &= B(B^TB)^{-1}(((B^TB)^{-1})^TB^TB(B^TB)^{-1})^{-1} \label{trans}
\end{align}
Here \eqref{subst} is due to the substitution $D=B(B^TB)^{-1}$, and \eqref{trans} is by the transpose law for matrix multiplication.
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
\(
\arraycolsep 0pt
\begin{array}{lcl}
    D(D^TD)^{-1} &\underbrace{=}_{\mathclap{D=B(B^TB)^{-1}}}
         & B(B^TB)^{-1}((B(B^TB)^{-1})^TB(B^TB)^{-1})^{-1} \\
      &= & B(B^TB)^{-1}(((B^TB)^{-1})^TB^TB(B^TB)^{-1})^{-1}
\end{array}
\)
```

[image]