# Align and underbrace

Tags: align

I got the following LaTeX-code (only an example):

```
\begin{align}
A=&0\\
0=& x y z re+ e\\
0\underbrace{=}_{\text{with bla bla bla bla}& u+z-24y
\end{align}
```

Now, I want that one equal signs is exactly the others, but the one where the underbrace is included is always shifted to the right.

Edit:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a+b=&0\\
0=&z+u+i+v\\
0\underbrace{=}_{\text{inserting bla bla bla}}&43+2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Your snippet is missing a `}` after "bla".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit (as so often) goes to egreg in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110463).

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\ueq}[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \sbox0{$\underbrace{=}_{}$}%
    \mathrel{\mathmakebox[\wd0]{=}}
  \else
    \mathrel{\underbrace{=}_{\mathclap{#1}}}
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A &\ueq 0\\
0 &\ueq x y z re+ e\\
0 &\ueq[\text{with bla bla bla bla}] u+z-24y
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]