# Alignement problem underbrace within \align

Tags: align

I can't get the alignment correct with the underbrace:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\sin \alpha  = \frac{|CD|}{b} \text{ en } \sin \beta  = \frac{|CD|}{a} \\
&\underbrace {b \cdot \sin \alpha  = |CD| \text{ en } a  \cdot \sin \beta  = |CD|}_ \Downarrow \\
b  \cdot \sin \alpha  &= a \cdot \sin \beta \\ 
\frac{b}{\sin \beta} &= \frac{a}{\sin \alpha} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I think the correct way is to make the first two rules as one block, and they should be aligned with the downarrow on the equal sign.

My question is different than [\underbrace and align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110460/underbrace-and-align-environment) 
because I want multiple lines above the underbrace that could be aligned one by one.

Comment: Why don't you just use `gather`?

Comment: @egreg I don't (didn't) know gather. I Started  2 years ago with align, and I'm using it ever since :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\underbrace and align environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110460/underbrace-and-align-environment)

Comment: @bers I've looked at that question before I started this question, but it doesn't give me an answer to my question ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you want `align` in this case, because there's no “natural” alignment point; so `gather` seems a better choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\sin \alpha  = \frac{|CD|}{b} \text{ en } \sin \beta  = \frac{|CD|}{a} \\
\underbrace {b \cdot \sin \alpha  = |CD| \text{ en } a  \cdot \sin \beta  = |CD|}_ \Downarrow \\
b  \cdot \sin \alpha  = a \cdot \sin \beta \\
\frac{b}{\sin \beta} = \frac{a}{\sin \alpha}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]